# Await is only valid in async function with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm developing a web capture app and it seems that all the functions are with async but console shows me a `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` error.

I tried to change all the functions to async but it seems still not working.
Is it an error because of the fs module? I think when I tried without fs module in another app it actually works.

Here's my full code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require('fs');

let galleryName = "frozen"; // Enter gallery name

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // Adjustments particular to this page to ensure we hit desktop breakpoint.
  page.setViewport({
    width: 1000,
    height: 10000,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1
  });

  fs.readFile('db.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let array = data.toString().split("\n");
    for (i in array) {
      console.log(`Now Processing : ${array[i]} ${array.length - i -1} left`);
      await page.goto(`https://gall.dcinside.com/${galleryName}/${array[i]}`), { // !!!!ERROR shows from here
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 0
      };
      async function screenshotDOMElement(opts = {}) {
        const padding = "padding" in opts ? opts.padding : 0;
        const path = "path" in opts ? opts.path : null;
        const selector = opts.selector;

        if (!selector) throw Error("Please provide a selector.");

        const rect = await page.evaluate(selector => {
          const element = document.querySelector(selector);
          if (!element) return null;
          const {
            x,
            y,
            width,
            height
          } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
          return {
            left: x,
            top: y,
            width,
            height,
            id: element.id
          };
        }, selector);

        if (!rect)
          throw Error(
            `Could not find element that matches selector: ${selector}.`
          );

        return await page.screenshot({
          path,
          clip: {
            x: rect.left - padding,
            y: rect.top - padding,
            width: rect.width,
            height: rect.height + padding * 2
          }
        });
      }

      await screenshotDOMElement({
        path: `./result/${pageNumArray[i]}.png`,
        selector: ".view_content_wrap",
        padding: 10
      });
    }
  });
  //   // await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: The function you pass to `fs.readFile` is not `async`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the callback function inside fs needs to be async as well,

```
fs.readFile('db.txt', async function (err, data) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers suggesting to make the callback `async` will make the error disappear, but the overall `readFile` operation will not be awaited. So, if for instance, you would enable the line with `await browser.close();`, that `browser.close()` will run before the `readFile` callback executes.

When you use promises, you are better off using the [Promise API for fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api):

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;

const handle = await fs.readFile('db.txt');
const data = await handle.readFile();
let array = data.toString().split("\n");
// ...etc


await handle.close();
```

This way:

- You don't have a callback, and you can use `await` with the file and other asynchronous operations
- The main `async` function's returned promise will only resolve when all `await`-tasks have been performed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **async** inside callback function then only you can able to use **await** otherwise you'll get the error.

```js
fs.readFile('db.txt', async (err, data) => { });
```

Answer (score 1):

**the callback function inside fs needs to be async as well**

this part :  `fs.readFile('db.txt', async function (err, data)`

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require('fs');

let galleryName = "frozen"; // Enter gallery name

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // Adjustments particular to this page to ensure we hit desktop breakpoint.
  page.setViewport({
    width: 1000,
    height: 10000,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1
  });

  fs.readFile('db.txt', async function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let array = data.toString().split("\n");
    for (i in array) {
      console.log(`Now Processing : ${array[i]} ${array.length - i -1} left`);
      await page.goto(`https://gall.dcinside.com/${galleryName}/${array[i]}`), { // !!!!ERROR shows from here
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 0
      };
      async function screenshotDOMElement(opts = {}) {
        const padding = "padding" in opts ? opts.padding : 0;
        const path = "path" in opts ? opts.path : null;
        const selector = opts.selector;

        if (!selector) throw Error("Please provide a selector.");

        const rect = await page.evaluate(selector => {
          const element = document.querySelector(selector);
          if (!element) return null;
          const {
            x,
            y,
            width,
            height
          } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
          return {
            left: x,
            top: y,
            width,
            height,
            id: element.id
          };
        }, selector);

        if (!rect)
          throw Error(
            `Could not find element that matches selector: ${selector}.`
          );

        return await page.screenshot({
          path,
          clip: {
            x: rect.left - padding,
            y: rect.top - padding,
            width: rect.width,
            height: rect.height + padding * 2
          }
        });
      }

      await screenshotDOMElement({
        path: `./result/${pageNumArray[i]}.png`,
        selector: ".view_content_wrap",
        padding: 10
      });
    }
  });
  //   // await browser.close();
})();
```

read more here about `async-await`'
 https://javascript.info/async-await